# Can't find error "Global symbol @xx requires explicit package name"

Tags: perl

I have checked the questions that may already have an answer and none of them have helped.

This is for my semester project for Unix Programming. I have created a script that compares HTML files to one other from a website.

The script worked perfectly as expected until I tried to implement the second website, so in turn I deleted the added code for the second website and now I get the errors

```
Global symbol "@master" requires explicit package name
Global symbol "@child" requires explicit package name
```

within the `csite_md5` subroutine. I have gone through the code many times over and cannot see the problem.

I am looking for another set of eyes to see if I'm just missing something simple, which usually is the case.

Also I am new to Perl as this is my first time using the language.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use File::Basename;

# Path to the c-site download root directory
my $csite_dir = '/root/websites/c-site/wget/';

opendir my $dh, $csite_dir or die $!;

# Finds the sub directories c-site_'date +%F' where the c-site download is located
my @wget_subdir_csite = sort grep /^[^.]/, readdir $dh;

# Creates the absolute path to the c-site download
my $csite_master_dir = "$csite_dir$wget_subdir_csite[0]/dayzunderground.webs.com";
my $csite_child_dir = "$csite_dir$wget_subdir_csite[1]/dayzunderground.webs.com";

# Call to subroutine to append the .html file name to the absolute path
my @master_csite = &gethtml_master_csite($csite_master_dir);
my @child_csite = &gethtml_child_csite($csite_child_dir);

&csite_md5(\@master_csite, \@child_csite);

sub gethtml_master_csite{

    my ($master_path) = @_;
    opendir (DIR, $master_path) or die $!;

    # Ends with .html and is a file
    my @html_master = sort grep {m/\.html$/i && -f "$master_path/$_"} readdir(DIR);

    my @files_master = ("$master_path/$html_master[0]","$master_path/$html_master[1]","$master_path/$html_master[2]","$master_path/$html_master[3]");

    return @files_master
}
sub gethtml_child_csite{

    my ($child_path) = @_;
    opendir (DIR, $child_path) or die $!;

    # Ends with .html and is a file
    my @html_child = sort grep {m/\.html$/i && -f "$child_path/$_"} readdir(DIR);

    my @files_child = ("$child_path/$html_child[0]","$child_path/$html_child[1]","$child_path/$html_child[2]","$child_path/$html_child[3]");

    return @files_child
}

sub csite_md5{

    my ($master, $child) = @_;

    if(&md5sum($master[0]) ne &md5sum($child[0])){

        my $filename = basename($master[0]);
        system("diff -u -d -t --width=100 $master[0] $child[0] > ~/websites/c-site/diff/c-site-$filename-`date +%F`");

        #print "1"
    }
    if(&md5sum($master[1]) ne &md5sum($child[1])){

        my $filename2 = basename($master[1]);
        system("diff -u -d -t --width=100 $master[1] $child[1] > ~/websites/c-site/diff/c-site-$filename2-`date +%F`");

        #print "2"
    }
    if(&md5sum($master[2]) ne &md5sum($child[2])){

        my $filename3 = basename($master[2]);
        system("diff -u -d -t --width=100 $master[2] $child[2] > ~/websites/c-site/diff/c-site-$filename3-`date +%F`");
        #print "3"
    }
    if(&md5sum($master[3]) ne &md5sum($child[3])){

        my $filename4 = basename($master[3]);
        system("diff -u -d -t --width=100 $master[3] $child[3] > ~/websites/c-site/diff/c-site-$filename4-`date +%F`");

        #print "4"
    }
}

sub md5sum{
    my $file = shift;
    my $digest = "";
    eval{
        open(FILE, $file) or die "Can't find file $file\n";
        my $ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
        $ctx->addfile(*FILE);
        $digest = $ctx->hexdigest;
        close(FILE);
    };
    if($@){
        print $@;
        return "";
    }
    return $digest
}
```

Comment: Dev's I apologize if this is a repeat question. I tried the other answers before making this post and they didn't help. Thank you for keeping Stackoverflow legit. I have learned a lot from using your platform.

Comment: Note that calling subroutines with an ampersand is a Perl 4 artifact and about twenty-two years out of date. Just `gethtml_child_csite($csite_child_dir)` is correct in Perl 5

Comment: Thank you Borodin for the information, should I have, use perl 5 at the top near use strict and so fourth?

Comment: No, all `use 5.010` etc. does is require a minimal version of Perl before the code will compile. At a glance I think any version of Perl 5 is fine with your code, it's just that adding an ampersand does very specific things that you almost certainly don't want. Just remove them

Comment: Thank you I will implement your suggestion after this test run of my utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$master` and `$child` are array references; use them like `$master->[0]`.  `$master[0]` uses the array `@master`, which is a completely separate variable.

Comment: I added @ to each $master and $child references e.g. @$master and @$child and now it works. Mind blowing how easy it was. I'm going to implement your advice. Thank you for your time...

Comment: Implemented and works, staying with your way because I guarantee you know more about perl than me. When I get 15 rep I will come back and upvote your answer. Thanks again ysth.

Comment: `@$arrayref[list-of-indexes]` is an array slice, a list of values from the array; given a single index, it is only subtly different from a single element lookup `$$arrayref[index]` / `$arrayref->[index]`.  you may want to look at http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: Thank you again ysth, I will definitely read into your reference. Also thank you again for all your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it may help to go through your program and point out some practices that are less than optimal

- You shouldn't use an ampersand `&` when calling a Perl subroutine. That was required in Perl 4 which was superseded about 22 years ago
- It is preferable to use the [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) module to manipulate file paths, both to handle cases like multiple path separators and for portability. `File::Spec` will also do the job of `File::BaseName`
- It is unnecessary to use the shell to create a date string. Use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module and `localtime->ymd` generates the same string as `date +%F`
- It is neater and more concise to use `map` where appropriate instead of writing multiple identical assignments
- The `gethtml_master_csite` and `gethtml_child_csite` subroutines are identical except that they use different variable names internally. They can be replaced by a single `gethtml_csite` subroutine
- You should use *lexical* file and directory handles throughout, as you have done with the first `opendir`. You should also use the three-parameter form of `open` (with the open mode as the second parameter)
- If an `open` fails then you should include the variable `$!` in the `die` string so that you know *why* it failed. Also, if you end the string with a newline then Perl won't append the source file and line number to the string when it is printed
- As you have read, the `csite_md5` attempts to use arrays `@master` and `@child` which don't exist. You have array *references* `$master` and `$child` instead. Also, the subroutine lends itself to a loop structure instead of writing the four comparisons explicitly
- In `md5sum` you have used an `eval` to catch the `die` when the `open` call fails. It is nicer to check for this explicitly
- The standard way of returning a *false* value from a subroutine is a bare `return`. If you `return ''` then it will evaluate as *true* in list context

With those chnages in place your code looks like this. Please ask if you have any problem understanding it. Note that I haven't been able to test it but it does compile

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use File::Spec::Functions qw/ catdir catfile splitpath /;
use Time::Piece 'localtime';

my $csite_dir = '/root/websites/c-site/wget/';

opendir my $dh, $csite_dir or die qq{Unable to open "$csite_dir": $!};

my @wget_subdir_csite = sort grep /^[^.]/, readdir $dh;

my ($csite_master_dir, $csite_child_dir) = map
        catdir($csite_dir, $_, 'dayzunderground.webs.com'),
        @wget_subdir_csite[0,1];

my @master_csite = gethtml_csite($csite_master_dir);
my @child_csite  = gethtml_csite($csite_child_dir);

csite_md5(\@master_csite, \@child_csite);

sub gethtml_csite {

    my ($path) = @_;

    opendir my $dh, $path or die qq{Unable to open "$path": $!};
    my @files = sort grep { /\.html$/i and -f } map catfile($path, $_), readdir $dh;

    return @files;
}

sub csite_md5 {

    my ($master_list, $child_list) = @_;

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#$master_list ) {

        my ($master, $child) = ($master_list->[$i], $child_list->[$i]);

        if ( md5sum($master) ne md5sum($child) ) {
            my $filename = (splitpath($master))[-1]; # Returns (volume, path, file)
            my $date = localtime->ymd;
            system("diff -u -d -t --width=100 $master $child > ~/websites/c-site/diff/c-site-$filename-$date");
        }
    }
}

sub md5sum {

    my ($file) = @_;
    my $digest = "";

    open my $fh, '<', $file or do {
        warn qq{Can't open file "$file": $!};   # '
        return;
    };

    my $ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
    $ctx->addfile($fh);

    return $ctx->hexdigest;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, opinions vary on some of these things.  one of the things Borodin lists is IMO completely a matter of taste and one is (again IMO) just wrong.

Comment: @ysth: I would welcome your comments about those points you disagree with

Comment: Borodin thank you for your in depth response and time. I am grateful for all your suggestions and your implementation of the sub par Perl code I have written. I can see exactly what everything is doing in your code. Also thank you for showing me how to make my subroutines scalable. I will definitely be referring back to your suggestions and implementation when I redo this project.